# Ubuntu 18.04 don't see Ethernet connection

Tags: 18.04, network-manager, ethernet

My Ubuntu has lost Ethernet connection.

[sudo lshw -C network response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUKXU.jpg)

I've returned file `10-globally-managed-devices` to empty.

regarding other two required actions. I don't have folder "/interface", instead I have this content in "/network" folder [cat /etc/network/ content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTAOh.jpg)
and bash request

cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml provides this response:

```
network: 
  version: 2 
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Comment: Set the file `10-globally-managed-devices` back to default. Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`.

Comment: @heynnema see my edits please.

Comment: Thanks for the info. However, in the future, please use copy/paste for textual output, instead of screenshots. Thanks. In looking at your `lshw` output, it looks like you've got a bad cable, or the cable is disconnected. Please describe your network cabling connections from the computer to the router/modem.

Comment: Thank you @heynnema for help. In the end I've had to reinstall Ubuntu and now it's all working

Comment: Thanks for the update!